# How to make an Submit button using Django Forms with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a website in Django in which I am using Django Form ,an my fields are

```
admin = forms.BooleanField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
    label=(u'Admin for the account')
)
owner = forms.BooleanField(
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
    label=(u'Owner for the account')
)
```

In my html page I want a submit button,On clicking which it will show a pop up ,In which you have an OK button,On clicking which the value of owner (Checkbox) will go.

Comment: just create a submit button in the bottom of the form and then attach a validate function to that form . This function got invoked when submit button on that form is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the documentation of [`Form class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-form-class)

> Note that it does not include the `<form>` tags, or a `submit` button. We’ll have to provide those ourselves in the template.

As for following additional functionalities:

> In my html page I want a submit button,On clicking which it will show
>   a pop up ,In which you have an OK button,On clicking which the value
>   of owner (Checkbox) will go.

You will need to write custom javascript functions if you want to do this. You can use `jquery` plugin for this. There is more documentation on submitting the form using jquery and additional handling [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include submit button manually in the html.

Sample Code: Note that I used bootstrap Modal.

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <!-- your input field will go here -->
  <!-- Small modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Submit</button>

  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="user"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Okay">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```